# os.walk failure on raspberry pi

Tags: python, linux

My code is failing at the line: for dirName... os.walk(). 
I just want to retrieve a list of the files in the source folder. I've used this command before (works fine on Win) but I'm trying to get the same code running on my raspberry pie (Linux) and now it doesn't work...?

```
import os
import os.path
src = '/home/data/'
ext = '.hpl'
fns=[]
print src
print ext
print 'Starting'
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(src, topdown=True):
    print('Found directory: %s' % dirName)
    for fname in fileList:
        print('\t%s' % fname)
        if fname.lower().endswith(ext):
            fn = os.path.join(dirName,fname)
            fns.append(fn)
print 'Ending the code'
return fns
```

When I run this, the output is: 
prints source (/home/data/)
prints ext (.hpl)
prints 'Starting'
prints 'Ending the code'

No matter what I try, it skips the entire "for dirName...os.walk..." segment. Not sure what's wrong with my statement?

Side note: actually it prints src as /home/data/{musical note}, where musical note=a tiny musical note beat symbol next to the /. I've never seen this before...

Comment: possibly an unprintable symbol that is stuck in your string but not shown. try to re-write the content of `src`

Comment: What do you have in `/home/data/` ?..Can we have a representation tree or something similar?..does it have folders and files with non-alphanumerical characters ?

Comment: Plus..is this Python2 or Python3?..I see you have too version of `print` ?

Comment: Is `/home/data` a symbolic link? os.walk ignores those by default, I don't know if that includes the toplevel one, but you could test `os.walk(src, topdown=True, followlinks=True)`

Comment: Instead of printing `dirName` directly, print `repr(dirName)` and see if some character is giving you trouble.

Answer (score 1):

It was an unprintable symbol (not sure how it got there??) at the end of src that caused it to crash. Anyways, fixed it once I re-wrote out `src = .../`. I have no idea where the unprintable symbol came from though.

Comment: I'll give you an upvote just for coming back and letting us know what happened. I still wish you would have used the advice I gave to figure out the exact character, since I'm having trouble figuring out what symbol wouldn't show up in the source but would print as a musical note at runtime.